# Improving MySQL read time, MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, database-normalization

I have a table with more than a million record with the following structure:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Measurement;
+----------------+---------+-----------------+------+------+
| Time_stamp     | Channel | SSID            | CQI  | SNR  |
+----------------+---------+-----------------+------+------+
| 03_14_14_30_14 |       7 | open            |   40 |  -70 |
| 03_14_14_30_14 |       7 | roam            |   31 |  -79 |
| 03_14_14_30_14 |       8 | open2           |   28 |  -82 |
| 03_14_14_30_15 |       8 | roam2           |   29 |  -81 |....
```

I am reading data from this table into python for plotting. The problem is, the MySQL reads are too slow and it is taking me hours to get the plots even after using 
MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor (as suggested by a few in this forum) to quicken up the task.

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'conti', 'My_Freqs', cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor);
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select Time_stamp FROM Measurement")
for row in cursor:
    ... Do processing ....
```

Will normalizing the table help me in speeding up the task? If so, How should i normalize it?

P.S: Here is the result for EXPLAIN

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Time_stamp | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Channel    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SSID       | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CQI        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SNR        | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Do you really have to read the whole table to generate your plots? Couldn't you use at least a WHERE clause to get only the necessary data?

Comment: I use the WHERE clause to get specific data for separate plots. But the entire table will be read. thanks..

Comment: Run [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on your query and then post the results here (if indeed the problem is on the MySQL side).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I have posted the result of EXPLAIN. thanks..

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The problem is with MySQL side as i am printing the times when this query starts and ends. Also top shows MySQL utilizes 100% of CPU.

Comment: Well obviously since your table has no keys whatsoever. Try adding a key on the `Time_stamp` column and the column that you are using for `WHERE`.

Comment: Is there a good reason your time stamp isn't an actual time/date type?  Parsing date strings and building date objects is pretty expensive.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething: That string is provided by the client side. Converting it into MySQL datetime and then storing it was even more expensive for me. So i am using strptime in python while plotting. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are looping over the cursor instead of just dumping out all the data at once and then processing it. You should be able to dump out a couple million rows in a couple/few seconds. Try to do something like

```
cursor.execute("select Time_stamp FROM Measurement")
data = cusror.fetchall()
for row in data: 
   #do some stuff...
```

Comment: The cursor is dumping all the data at once. But I have to get the channels available during each timestamp. So i will execute something like "Select Channel FROM Measurement WHERE Time_stamp='%s'" in a loop for each timestamp.

Comment: Thats not the right way to go here. That is where the slowdown is. It is going to be very much faster if you do a total dump and then process in Python than do a new sql select for each row in the database again.

Comment: also, 'for row in cursor' is not the same thing as data=cursor.fetchall()

Comment: I believe that your method is doing a sql call for each row, instead of doing only 1 sql call for the whole dataset if you do a fetchall()

Comment: You could also use a GROUPBY in SQL (or python) to do this.

Comment: Hi when using SSCursor(), the default cursor fetches all the data at once, even if you don't use fetchall().. However, i will try not to do it in a loop and update the result tomorrow. I was avoiding it because parsing 5 million values in a python list is equally time consuming. Isnt it?

Comment: Not necessarily slower in python. I would definitely do a SQL GROUPBY instead of multiple selections as you are doing now though.

Comment: The SQL GROUP BY is a good idea, as long as you have something to compute on each timestamp group, like an AVG or a COUNT or a SUM... Otherwise, what you really need is to ORDER BY Timestamp. In both cases, and even if you stick to your original queries, you need to create an INDEX on the Timestamp column. Maybe you have one already? What does the EXPLAIN look like when you query for a certain timestamp?

Comment: `fetchall()` will only fetch upto the maxsize for the cursor (which isn't even close to 1 million)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're saying the *whole* table *has* to be read, I guess you can't do much about it. It has more than 1 million records... you're not going to optimize much on the database side.

How much time does it take you to process just one record? Maybe you could try optimizing that part. But even if you got down to 1 millisecond per record, it would still take you about half an hour to process the full table. You're dealing with a lot of data.

Maybe run multiple plotting jobs in parallel? With the same metrics as above, dividing your data in 6 equal-sized jobs would (theoretically) give you the plots in 5 minutes.

Do your plots have to be fine-grained? You could look for ways to ignore certain values in the data, and generate a complete plot only when the user needs it (wild speculation here, I really have no idea what your plots look like)

Comment: Plotting is not taking that much of time. So plotting in parallel may not save a great deal of time. If you mean MySQL reads in parallel, i can try that. Ignoring values is not an option atleast for the time being :)